# Error when using Storybook and React-Hook-Form (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef'))

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-hook-form, storybook

I want to make a catalog for components that I made.
But I've got error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef').

Using languages and libraries

- next.js "13.3.0"
- typescript "5.0.4"
- react-hook-form "^7.43.9"
- storybook "^7.0.5"

A few components are using react-hook-form.
When I was making catalog for them. The storybook logs the error of "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')".
I guess this is due to the useForm from react-hook-form that refers the value of the input by useRef before the component was mounted.
Is there any idea that solves this error?

The version of storybook, react-hook-forms and the others are below.

```
{
  "name": "my-app-fontmock",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/react": "18.0.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "eslint": "8.38.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
    "next": "13.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.9",
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "yup": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.5",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.5",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.5",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.5",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.0.5",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.5",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.11",
    "storybook": "^7.0.5"
  }
}
```

And the component and stories files are like these.

Component

```
import React from "react";
import { UseFormRegister, FieldValues } from "react-hook-form";

type SelectBoxOption = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
};

export type SelectProps = {
  name: string;
  labelText: string;
  register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>;
  options: SelectBoxOption[];
};

export const Select = ({ name, options, register, labelText }: SelectProps) => {
  return (
    <label>
      {labelText}
      <select {...register(name)}>
        {options.map((option: SelectBoxOption) => (
          <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </label>
  );
};
```

Stories file

```
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
import {Select} from '../components/Select';
import { FieldValues, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const select_box_options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" },
];

const meta: Meta<typeof Select> = {
  title: 'Components/React-Hook-Form/Select',
  component: Select,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
};

// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<FieldValues>();


export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof Select>;

// More on writing stories with args: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args
export const Normal: Story = {
  args: {
    name: "flavor",
    labelText: "flavor",
    register: register,
    options: select_box_options,
  },
};
```

Caller of the component

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm, SubmitHandler, FieldValues } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Select } from "../components/Select";

const select_box_options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" },
];

function select() {

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<FieldValues>({
  });


  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Select
            name="Flavor"
            labelText="Flavor"
            register={register}
            options={select_box_options}
          />
          <input type="submit" />
      </form>
  );
}

export default select;
```

I'm looking forward to hearing any idea from you.
Thank you!